# Clearing a listbox

Tags: c#, multithreading, listbox

I'm working on a chat-program. The chat works. The GUI on the client-side has 1 textarea to show all chat messages, 1 textfield and 1 button to send a message and 1 listbox which contains all acutally connected clientnames with the server.
If one client has connected to the server, the server sends a specific code which calls a "requestClientnamelist()"-method on the clientside, which requests the actually clientnamelist from the server and put this list in his listbox.

And here is my problem:
Before i refill the listbox with the actually clientnamelist, i want to clear this listbox first so i have not any twice names in this listbox. But the listbox1.Clear() method does not clean anything! The filling of the listbox works, but the clearing of the old clientnamelist does not work...

Here is my code (This code called from a different thread (not the GUI-Thread!)):

```
                        // Clear and refill Clientnamelist in mainframe
                        try {
                            mainframe.Invoke((Action)delegate {
                                mainframe.listBox1.Items.Clear();

                                for (int i = 0; i < client.clientnameList.Count; i++) {
                                    mainframe.listBox1.Items.Add(client.clientnameList[i]);
                                }

                            });
                        } catch (ObjectDisposedException e) {
                            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                        }
```

Comment: FYI: you can call `Console.WriteLine(e)` and it will produce much more detailed output.

Comment: Why are you catching only ObjectDisposedException?

Comment: The.Clear() ought to work, if you see double names then go look for another piece of code that fill your listbox.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah... you're going to have to Invoke/BeginInvoke the listbox actions:(

Comment: I'm doing this already in my startpost?! I'm confused, have you a little code-snippet about what do you exactly mean?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this delegate functions to access Main UI control from other threads. It is a delegate functions that can be **reused**!

```
private delegate void InvokeAction();
        private void DoUI(InvokeAction call)
        {
            if (IsDisposed)
            {
                return;
            }
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                try
                {
                    Invoke(call);
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException)
                {
                    //Alert?
                }
            }
            else
            {
                call();
            }
        }
```

You can call the DoUI like this

```
        DoUI(() =>
        {
             mainframe.listBox1.Items.Clear();
        });
```

Therefore, can you give a try on this (delegate on listbox clear and listbox item added) and see if it solves your problem? (It should work on listbox because the reference page of the above delegate, "[How can solve "Cross-thread operation not valid"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045941/how-can-solve-cross-thread-operation-not-valid)" also using ListBox1 as example (by GvS).

```
        try {
                    DoUI(() =>
                    {
                        mainframe.listBox1.Items.Clear();
                    });
                    for (int i = 0; i < client.clientnameList.Count; i++) {
                        DoUI(() =>
                        {
                            mainframe.listBox1.Items.Add(client.clientnameList[i]);
                        });
                    }
            } catch (ObjectDisposedException e) {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code from my startpost was working already. My mistake was that i forgot to clear the client.clientnameList.
Tanks and sorry!